# Echo JSON -> Arrays in PHP

Tags: php, json

I've been trying to read a JSON string in PHP since yesterday, but I always fail. Can you help me?

> {"WEAPON_PISTOL":{"ammo":227}}

TO

> ECHO: WEAPON_PISTOL WITH 227 Ammunition

I've tried this way up until now:

```
$json_string = "{"WEAPON_PISTOL":{"ammo":227}}";
$obj = json_decode($json_string,true);   
for($i=0;$i<count($obj);$i++) {
   echo $obj[$i];
   echo $obj[$i]["ammo];
}
```

Comment: What's your question about this? Is there any error given? Is the output different than expected?

Comment: I would like to read out the JSON string in order to display the content.

Comment: And I don't get a error no.

Comment: Why put such bad code in your question? I think you can do better. You force your `json_decode()` to return an array and then call it `$obj`? You're missing a double quote behind `"ammo`? This code cannot even execute.

Comment: `I don't get a error no`...well what _do_ you get, then?

Comment: If you don't get an error, how did you know that you "failed"?

Comment: Your edited code still would not compile due to the quote marks in the hard-coded string. Please double-check what you're doing when posting, otherwise it just diverts the energy of those trying to help you, because we usually can't tell the difference between typos you've made when showing the code here and the code you're actually running. There was no need to substitute that hard-coded value in, you already showed us what the JSON looks like. Always just copy-and-paste your real code - no substitutions, no re-typing. Thanks.

Comment: This code _should_ be producing errors and/or warnings. If you see no output, go and switch on PHP error reporting.

Comment: Once we fix the basic typo/quoting issues, we see that even then it doesn't work because you're trying to access a numeric index in an associative array. Errors demo: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/71bd09cec4df46a265dd263d54887688ac857285 . Since it's an associative array (from a JSON _object_) I don't know why you tried to loop through it with a `for`? `foreach` is far better because it lets you access the object _and_ the key name, which you need for your example. Working demo: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/8f9d1afd5c3be43899e52893f542bedd989c9d2b

Comment: Thank you for your answer, that was exactly the solution to the problem I was looking for :)

Answer (score 1):

The way to access the value of "ammo" is:

```
$json_string = '{"WEAPON_PISTOL":{"ammo":227}}';
$obj = json_decode($json_string); 
echo $obj->WEAPON_PISTOL->ammo;
```

This returns:

```
227
```

If you want to loop through several weapons, even though your example only contains one weapon, you can do:

```
$json_string ='{"WEAPON_PISTOL":{"ammo":227}, 
                "WEAPON_GUN":{"ammo":6}}';
$weapons = json_decode($json_string); 
foreach ($weapons as $weaponName => $weapon) {
    echo "$weaponName has $weapon->ammo rounds.\n";
}
```

This returns:

```
WEAPON_PISTOL has 227 rounds.
WEAPON_GUN has 6 rounds.
```

Comment: Thank you, I've come this far, but I have the problem that I have several WEAPON_*** for this I also had a for loop on my code "$i"

Comment: @realBlxcky I added that to my answer.